# Call C# class from VBA

Tags: c#, vba

Please can some1 tell me as to what is wrong with my code?

C#:

```
namespace ComMsg
{
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IM
{
    [DispId(1)]
    event M.MHandler OnMSend;
}

[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IMEvents
{
    [DispId(2)]
    void sendM(M.Process status, string msg);
}

[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IM), typeof(IMEvents))]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class Message : IM
{
    public enum Process { Error, Complete }

    public delegate void MHandler(Process status, string msg);
    public event MHandler OnMSend;

    public void sendM(Process status, string msg)
    {
        if (OnMSend != null)
            OnMSend(status, msg);
    }
}
}
```

I call this from my VBA code

```
Private WithEvents moCom     As ComMsg.M

Public Function Run() As Boolean
Set moCom = New ComMsg.M
```

it fails at

> New ComMsg.Message

and i get an error message

> "Object or class does not support the set of events"

Please help to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# to VB6 COM events ("object or class does not support the set of events")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881305/c-sharp-to-vb6-com-events-object-or-class-does-not-support-the-set-of-events)

Comment: VBA is usually pretty cranky about interfaces that are not marked as [default].  Try declaring only *one* event interface.

Comment: whats the use of DispID? Is it really necessary?

Comment: whenever i pass parameters (Process status, string msg) it gives me an error.. any suggestions??? without parameters it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing quite a lot of the settings required to implement COM interop. The suggested duplicate link addresses a similar issue.

It might also be worth looking at the MSDN Com interop example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3fd4a20.aspx) for all the various settings you need to include to use COM interop.

Comment: I have edited my C# code but i still get the error. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: whenever i pass parameters (Process status, string msg) it gives me an error.. any suggestions??? without parameters it works fine