# Compile error when using WithEvents and a .NET object

Tags: .net, vb6, interop, com-interop

I get a compile error `"object does not source automation events"` on this line in VB6:

```
Private WithEvents obj As MyClass
```

`MyClass` is a COM-visible .NET class.

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: I don't know the cause of that, but: it must be observed that VB6 is 4 years into an afterlife... Is this question addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881305/c-sharp-to-vb6-com-events-object-or-class-does-not-support-the-set-of-events?

Comment: This means there are no events (source interface) defined for `MyClass` coclass.

@Marc: It must be observed that there are still questions being asked about VB6. FORTRAN too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that MyClass does not have any public events (accessible via COM Interop).

If the .NET object was created in VB.Net, you can use the standard `Event` keyword as with VB6. C# will require the `event` keyword and an associated `delegate`. COM Interop will handle the conversion between .NET events and COM events.